# Flask - How can I delete data ranging back X days?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Flask SQLAlchemy and Postgres, I was wondering how can I delete data from a table if it goes back, for example 7 days from the CURRENT date.

My table has 3 rows, name, hobby and a date_posted, all of them are STRING.

The datetime format I am using is

```
"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Comment: Impossible to answer if you don't tell us what your `datetime` format is, since you've stored it as a string. ISO8601 I hope

Comment: Sorry, updated. You are correct, ISO8601.

Comment: `DELETE FROM my_table WHERE DATEDIFF(day, my_table.date_posted, CURRENT_DATE) = 7`?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget but that's a raw query, not leveraging SQLA :(

Comment: Yes, I am usually working with queries such as ```User.query.all()``` to get back all of the rows from that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *only works* if you store your datetime in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. There may be other formats that allow for the same lexicographical ordering; I'm just not aware of them so I'm being safe.

Really, it would be easier if you stored in `DateTime` format, but anyway.

```
import datetime as dt

DAYS = 30

cutoff = (dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(days=DAYS)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
User.query.filter_by(date_added<=cutoff).delete()
db.session.commit()
```

If you *do* start storing timestamps as `DateTime` but want to filter by date, you can use [`cast` and `Date`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333014/convert-selected-datetime-to-date-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: Got it, thank you so much. I will reformat my table so it takes in a DateTime instead of a string!

Comment: It'll be much easier. I can add a little extra how to deal with `DateTime` vs `Date` types if that's helpful, @RobinsonDickinson

Comment: Sure, that would be helpful.

Comment: @RobinsonDickinson you should use `DateTime(timezone=True)` whenever you can. timestamps without time-zones are mainly there to support older DBs. If you create a new DB you should add time-zones. It is a are critical piece of information for time-related data. Even if you are using UTC because otherwise you will never know if you need to apply DST or not.

Comment: @exhuma totally valid point. I'm half tempted to add it to my answer but I'd rather give you the chance to add another answer. I (think) I fixed the comparison in the question itself, but happy to upvote that